# 編集画面のタイトルやタグ欄でEnterを押しても投稿されないようにしてほしい

Tags: 機能の要求, 対応予定

編集画面で本文以外の欄にカーソルがあるとき、IME入力決定では無いタイミングで <kbd>Enter</kbd> を押すと投稿してしまいます。タイトルやタグ欄から素早く投稿する必要性はないと思うので、IME関連で <kbd>Enter</kbd> をよく使う日本語環境でこの機能はいらないのではないでしょうか。

---

In question/answer edit mode, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while not in IME with the cursor placed in a single lined text box (Title, Tag, Edit Summery) results in a submission. I am aware that this is the default behavior of HTML, but since there is no requirement for fast submission and because Japanese input uses <kbd>Enter</kbd> often for IME, is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: textarea以外のフォーム項目でEnter押すとsubmitされるのはブラウザのデフォルト動作のような気が…ここではあまり必要性がないのも確かではありますが。

Comment: @unarist 1行フォームでEnterがsubmitってデフォルトだったんですね、初めて知りました。JS書けば防げるみたいですが、[Japanese Language](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/)も同じ仕様なので、すぐには変えられ無いかもしれませんね…

Comment: チャットとか、コメントとか、わりとしょっちゅう暴発、しますね。「本当に投稿しますか？」のダイアログが表示されるぐらいがちょうどいいかもしれないとは思わなくもないです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yuki Inoueさんの回答のように、IMEが日本語の場合「Enter」で投稿しませんが、IMEが英語の場合ネットワークと同じように「Enter」で投稿します。

対策として、当サイトでIMEの言語にかかわらずに「Enter」で投稿しないように設定します。

（設定を作るまでにちょっと時間がかかります。今週末までお待ち下さい）

Comment: Skypeなどのように Ctrl+Enter で送信できると、誤操作は減らしつつ利便性も確保できていいかもしれません。私はこのパターンが好きです。

Answer (score 2):

https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/please-disable-enter-to-submit-comments

によれば、 Japanese SE ではこの対応が行われたようなので、（どうやって実現されたのかはいまいちわかっていないですが。。）ここのサイトでも、この対応は行えるのではないか、と思っています。

Comment: それはIMEの確定時に送信されてしまうのをなんとかしてほしい、という話で、[このサイトでも過去に実施されていました](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1780/8000)が、[それが解決したので元に戻した](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2217/8000)ようです。そのバグが起きていたことからもコメント欄ではJSのキーイベントをわざわざ拾っていたのだと思うので、編集画面とは事情が異なるような気がします。

Comment: @unarist Oh... (字数稼ぎ。… reputation でこの制限はとっぱらえないのだろうか。)