# Enterキーの望ましい挙動についての意見募集

Tags: 討議

投稿を作成中のEnterキーの押下はどのような挙動が望ましいでしょうか。現在の挙動を変更した方がよい場所はありますでしょうか。

この件は、過去に何回か話題になりましたが、どれも経過が不明、あるいはStack Exchange社と話が噛み合わないまま終っています。時間が経っていることもあり、改めて意見を募集したいです。

変更が必要という意見が多ければ、改めて議論を取りまとめ、要望として投稿する予定です。議論や質問を終らせた後に端的にまとめることにより、誤解が生じる可能性を減らせると考えています。

変更が必要なさそうであれば、過去の投稿も一旦は完了という扱いにしたいです。

#### 考慮が必要な要素

- 入力場所:

  - タイトルやタグの入力欄
  - コメントの入力欄
- 挙動:

  - 投稿を送信する
  - 投稿を送信しない（投稿するにはボタンにフォーカスを移してからの押下か、クリックが必要）

#### 現状

- タイトルやタグの入力欄: 送信する
- コメントの入力欄: 送信する
- インプットメソッドがONの場合: どこでも送信しない

#### 他サイトの挙動

- Qiita、Zenn:

  - タイトルやタグの入力欄: 送信しない
  - コメントの入力欄: 送信しない（複数行なので当然）
- GitHub Gist、GitLab Snippet:

  - タイトルの入力欄： 送信する
  - コメントの入力欄： 送信しない（複数行なので当然）

#### 過去の議論

- [コメント入力中でのEnterの動作](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2496/3054): 2017年の要望には「IME使用中の変換確定時のEnterで送信されると言う話ではありません」と書かれていましたが、「日本語 IME モードで Enter キーが押された場合、コメントは投稿されません」として完了になってしまいました。
- [編集画面のタイトルやタグ欄でEnterを押しても投稿されないようにしてほしい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2357/3054): 2016年の要望は対応予定のままです。
- [Enterキーでコメントを送信することができない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1780/3054): 2015年時点ではこれが仕様として実装されていたようです。

Comment: この投稿の意向として「変更したい」あるいは「このままにしたい」という意見がないので投票しづらいなと思っています。mjy さんのやりたい変更があれば質問か回答に投稿いただけるとありがたいです。それか意見がある方がいらっしゃれば回答いただければ。

Comment: @nekketsuuu  私には意見が無いです。皆さんの意見を募集しています。
意見が無ければ、それはそれで良いことだと思います。
つまり、現状で問題が無いということですから。
IM使用中のEnterを無効にするだけで、実際的なニーズが満たせている、ということでしょう。

Comment: この意見は長期間（少なくとも1カ月以上）募集するつもりです。

Comment: [注目] タグを追加して、コミュニティのより沢山の人がこの議論に参加できるようにすることをお勧めします。

Comment: 要望をまとめて投稿しました。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3950

Answer (score 5):

個人的にしょっちゅう誤爆するのでEnterキーで送信しない挙動が望ましいです。
私ほどの粗忽者になるとIMオフを認識せずにEnterするどころかIM使用中のEnterキーをなぜか連打して投稿します。

5分以内(?)に編集すれば良いという意見ももっともですが、編集中は意図しないコメントが公開されますし推敲して5分以上経過することもあります。
なので私はメモ帳に書き出してコピペする手間をかけています。

コメントは単純なひと手間なのでまだ良いのですが、私は普段ログインせずに閲覧しているので回答の書き込み時もログインしてコピペ投稿することがあります。
ログイン直後に長文投稿挙動するとCAPTCHAが発動するようで、解除のためにふた手間かかります。

さすがに質問/回答時のコピペに対応していただきたいとは思わないものの、現在のコメント仕様に積極的な理由がなく、改修が容易であるならば下記の挙動が望ましいです。

- タイトルやタグの入力欄: 送信しない
- コメントの入力欄: 送信しない(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>で送信する)
- インプットメソッドがONの場合: どこでも送信しない
- 質問/回答テキストの入力欄: 送信しない

Comment: Ctrl+Enterについては「あれば若干便利で使う」程度のニュアンスで、hopeではなくwishの意味合いです。

Comment: コメント欄と質問/回答テキストがごっちゃになっていたので編集しました。テキストのCtrl+Enterは特に要望しません。

Comment: 確認です。「インプットメソッドがONの場合: どこでも送信しない」の部分ですが、OFFの場合に送信して欲しい場所が有りますか？

Comment: @mjy OFFの場合も「どこでも送信しない」ことを希望します。

Comment: [要望をまとめたもの](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3950/)を投稿するにあたって、今回は Ctrl+Enter の件を含めないことにしました。
現在、Stack Exchange社との意思疎通にやや自信が持てなく、if then 的な内容を入れるのが不安でした。
CAPTCHAの発動タイミングに関しては、全サイト的に議論が可能だと思いますので、 [Meta Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) への投稿もありだと思います。
自分も同事象に見まわれたら投稿するかも知れません。

Comment: @mjy 取りまとめありがとうございます。Ctrl+Enterを含めない点について承知いたしました。投稿してくださった内容に異存はございません。

Answer (score 3):

> あるいはStack Exchange社と話が噛み合わないまま終っています

本件結局状況変わってないので改めてリクエスト投げようかなと思ったこともありましたが、現在では、この「話がかみ合わない」を改善しないとどうにもならないのだろうと思ってます。
本件に限らず、この「話がかみ合ってない」状況は散見されます。

ただ、この問題提起をしても高い確率で「話がかみ合わない」状況で終わるのは目に見えてるので、本件に対しても、他に改善してほしい事柄についても、何かアクションをする気にならない、というのが現状です。

Comment: 申し訳ありません、反省しております。この状況を改善できるよう、サポートさせていただきたいです。

Answer (score 3):

Enterで送信しない挙動を希望します。

日本語ですと文字入力中のEnterキー押下は変換の確定という意味で使われますし、
状況(変換待ちか変換確定後か)によって変換の確定と送信という全く違う意味を持つのは混乱してしまいます。

https://japan.cnet.com/article/35110559/
https://inquire.jp/2017/11/22/slack-newrelease/
上記の記事によると、2017年のslack日本上陸時には
Enterキーでの送信は日本語では相応しくないので送信ボタンを新設＆日本語設定だと送信コマンドがCtrl+Enterに。
の変更が入ったようで、日本語圏ではEnter送信は不便という認識だと思います。
(それまでSlackって送信ボタンが存在しなかったのか…？)

ただ、スタックオーバーフローはSlackの様なチャットツールではなく質問サイトであり
文章はそれなりに思慮添削するので、Ctrl+Enterのショートカットキーで投稿する事は無いだろうなとも思いますが。