# Enterキーを押しても投稿が送信されないようにして下さい

Tags: 機能の要求, 調査中

投稿（質問、回答、コメント）を編集中のEnterキーの動作に関して、変更を希望いたします（ここでの「編集」は、新規投稿の作成も、既存の投稿の編集も含みます）。

#### 変更内容

##### 現状

- 現在は投稿を編集中に単一行の入力欄でEnterキーを押すと、投稿が送信されます。
- IM（インプットメソッド / IME）がONの際には、送信されません（この動作は、環境により異なるかも知れません）。

##### 希望する動作

- 投稿を編集中に単一行の入力欄でEnterキーを押しても、投稿が送信されないようにして下さい。単一行の入力欄には下記があります。

  - タイトル
  - タグ
  - 編集サマリー
  - コメント
- この際、IMの状態を考慮する必要は有りません。つまり、IMがONであっても、OFFであっても、Enterキーの入力では投稿が送信されないようにしてください。
- 送信ボタンにフォーカスがある際の動作は今まで通りで大丈夫です。

#### 理由

日本語の入力においては、IMが使用されます。そして、多くのIMの操作ではEnterキーが多用されます。結果として現在の仕様ですと、Enterキーの誤操作による投稿の送信が多発しているので、変更が必要です。

繰り返しになりますが、IMに関係する問題ではあっても、IMの状態の考慮は必要ありません。現在のようにIMがONの場合だけEnterキーによる送信を無効にしていても、誤操作が発生しています。Enterキーの動作がモードにより異なり、一方のモードでは送信という重要な結果を招くことが問題となっています。

#### ユーザーの意見

この変更は複数のユーザーに要望されていて、投票による支持が得られています。今のところ、反対意見や反対票はありません。詳しくは、[事前の意見募集](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3923/3054)をご参照下さい。

Comment: 参考: MSE では10年以上前から議論しているようです。 [Pressing Enter in comment box unexpectedly submits form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63644/403540)